# ¿Es "eventualmente" una traducción válida de "eventually"?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras

Cada vez más oigo y leo frases como:

> No me gustan las patatas, pero sé que **eventualmente** me acabarán gustando.

Para mí esto es un [falso amigo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falso_amigo) de la palabra *eventually*, que quiere decir [*finalmente, al final, con el tiempo*...](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=eventually)..

Miré la definición en la RAE y me lo confirma:

> [**eventualmente**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=H9RF1l5)
>
> 1. adv. Incierta o casualmente.

Lo que me hace pensar, por ejemplo, en la palabra *eventual* y los [contratos eventuales](http://www.citapreviainem.es/el-contrato-eventual-por-circunstancias-de-la-produccion/).

Pero me pregunto: ¿acaso hay alguna acepción que me pasa desapercibida? ¿Es erróneo usarla como traducción de *eventually* o puede haber casos en que sí sea válida?

Comment: El diccionario WordReference muestra su significado como  *finalmente, al final* y *con el tiempo*. En todo caso la terminación *-ly* en inglés muestra el sufijo *-mente* en español, ha de ser por esta razón que se traduce como *eventualmente*.

Comment: Es (o fue) un calco erróneo sin duda, pero parece que va ganando fuerza.  Ninguna de las acepciones de *eventual* (el adjetivo base) implica finalidad, sino imprevisibilidad.  Fíjate que yo como anglohablante nativo que uso *eventually* con frecuencia en inglés, no creo haber dicho *eventualmente* en ningún momento en castellano.  Para ello, usuaría «al final (de todo)», «acabar + gerundio», «(alg)ún día».

Comment: @guifa Interesante, pero yo sí he usado *eventualmente*.

Comment: _Eventually_ puede ser también "tarde o temprano".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

De acuerdo con el Diccionario panhispánico de dudas, No debe utilizarse con el significado de 'al final o finalmente', es decir, no es equivalente con *eventually*

Cito de la referencia:

> No debe utilizarse con el significado de ‘al final o finalmente’, calco censurable del inglés eventually: «Tal vez por eso Castro terminó eventualmente desterrando al Che de Cuba» (DAméricas [EE. UU.] 15.4.97).

Nótese que la oración es un ejemplo de un mal uso de la palabra **eventualmente**

[Referencia](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=eventual)