# ¿Es "bizarro" en algún caso la traducción de "bizarre"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, préstamo-lingüístico

Últimamente oigo con cierta frecuencia frases del tipo:

> Acaba de salir un elefante del maletero de ese coche. ¡Qué situación
>   tan **bizarra**!

Es decir, se usa *bizarro* como sinónimo de raro, estrafalario. Como uno nunca sabe con certeza si todo lo que cree que es, es, he ido al DRAE para confirmar que la palabra significa lo que yo creo:

> **[bizarro, rra](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5dC5eFT)**
>
> Del it. bizzarro 'iracundo'.
>
> 1. adj. valiente (‖ arriesgado).
> 2. adj. Generoso, lucido, espléndido.

... y sí, nada que ver con cosas estrafalarias, por lo que parece que se ha incorporado la acepción de la palabra inglesa [bizarre](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bizarre?s=t): *markedly unusual in appearance, style, or general character and often involving incongruous or unexpected elements; outrageously or whimsically strange; odd: bizarre clothing; bizarre behavior*.

Sin embargo, no dejo de preguntarme: ¿hay algún contexto en el que este uso esté justificado o le pasa como a [*eventually*, incorrectamente traducido como *eventual*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/16381/1674)?

Comment: Pienso que se trata de otro _"False friend"_ más. No conozco ningún contexto donde bizarro tenga el sentido de "estafalario", pero sí que recuerdo haber visto esa traducción equivocada hace ya tiempo: En los comics españoles de Superman de los años 80 había un personaje feo y estrafalario que se llamaba "Bizarro". En ese momento no entendía la razón del nombre, porque el personaje en cuestión no era ni valiente ni generoso, sino más bien todo lo contrario. Ahora me doy cuenta de que el nombre del personaje en el original en inglés debía ser "Bizarre" y alguien hizo una traducción libre.

Comment: Yo siempre use Bizarro como estrafalario, surrealista. De hecho nunca escuche que se usara como valiente. No se si se debe a mi localizacion (Catalunya, España) o mi edad (20) pero para mi bizarro es sinonimo de bizarre

Comment: @Aimnox por lo que veo, tu situación es la más común en cada vez más sectores. Yo personalmente nunca usé tampoco la palabra _bizarro_ en su significado aceptado.

Comment: @Aimnox: Igual es por la edad, hace tiempo que dejé atrás los 20 ;) En cualquier caso, suscribo las palabras de Carlos Alejo en su excelente respuesta: _... dado que estamos rodeados y que el diccionario debe adecuarse al uso popular y no al revés, es cuestión de tiempo el que se acepte dicho significado._

Comment: @Ra_ de hecho podría no tardar demasiado. En el [artículo de Verne](http://verne.elpais.com/verne/2015/11/05/articulo/1446740407_989364.html) se ve cómo la RAE pasó de decir _El Diccionario de la RAE recoge el uso real de la lengua, no las modas, que son efímeras ¿Y si en 2 años ya no "tuiteamos"?_ en 2011 a aceptarlo en 2014.

Comment: Diccionario de americanismos: bizarro, -a.
I. 1. adj. PR, Ch, Ar. Referido a cosa, extraña, rara, insólita.
II. 1. adj. Ve. Bajo, despreciable, malsano. pop + cult → espon ^ desp. En francés, existe bizarre, también. No solo en inglés...

Comment: Así llegó al DRAE “cederrón”. Se dieron prisa y ya ves.

Comment: @aerobiomat y lo mismo pasará con el _SMS_...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No solamente en inglés tiene el significado de raro, estrafalario. También lo tiene en francés e italiano:

> **[bizarre](http://www.le-dictionnaire.com/definition.php?mot=bizarre)**
>
> *Adjectif singulier invariant en genre*
>
> - étrange, sortant de l'habituel
> - en qualifiant un individu, changeant, excentrique, capricieux

> **[biżżarro](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/bizzarro/)** agg. [etimo incerto]. – 1. Che attrae l’attenzione per la sua stranezza e originalità; fantastico, stravagante, capriccioso [...]. 2. a. ant. Irascibile, facile all’ira [...]. b. *Cavallo b.*, focoso, vivace, facile ad adombrarsi.

Yo estoy contigo, a día de hoy en español no hay contexto alguno en el que esté justificado su uso como "raro, estrafalario". Sin embargo, dado que estamos rodeados y que el diccionario debe adecuarse al uso popular y no al revés, es cuestión de tiempo el que se acepte dicho significado. Pero bueno, esto es una opinión propia. De momento el DPD advierte de [lo siguiente](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=bizarro):

> **bizarro -rra.** En español significa ‘valiente, esforzado’: *«Llega el capitán Andrés Cuevas, un bizarro combatiente al mando de un pelotón»* (Matos Noche [Cuba 2002]); y ‘lucido, airoso’: *«Vuestra juventud reverdecerá más bizarra y galana que nunca»* (Luján Espejos [Esp. 1991]). Debe evitarse su empleo con el sentido de ‘raro o extravagante’, calco semántico censurable del francés o del inglés *bizarre*: *«—Es un nombre bizarro. —No cuando se ha nacido en Sídney y se es australiana»* (Leyva Piñata [Méx. 1984]). Tampoco debe emplearse *bizarría* con el sentido de ‘rareza o extravagancia’.

Curiosamente en portugués se usa el significado español, pero además añade el francés como galicismo:

> **[bizarro](https://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/bizarro)**
>
> *(espanhol bizarro)
> adjectivo*
>
> - Que tem bizarria. (Garbo e galhardia no porte e no proceder.)
> - Próprio de quem tem bizarria
> - [Galicismo] Excêntrico.

Que es justo adonde opino que vamos a tender.

---

**[Actualización 2019]** Edito la respuesta en un añadido aparte, por no modificar sustancialmente la redacción de la misma.

El diccionario de americanismos de la ASALE sí que recoge el uso de *bizarro* que mencionas:

> **[bizarro, -a.](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=saJNg5fzBx0Ai6QhU3N)**
>
> I. 1. adj. *PR, Ch, Ar*. *Referido a cosa*, extraña, rara, insólita.
> II. 1. adj. *Ve*. Bajo, despreciable, malsano. pop + cult → espon ^ desp.

Se atestigua, pues, y como afirma @rsanchez en [su respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/17078/12637), su uso en Argentina, además de en Chile y Puerto Rico, con el sentido de "raro". Pero es más, la Fundéu afirma en [un artículo](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/bizarro-significa-raro-extravagante-valiente/) lo siguiente:

> También aparece recogido en el *Diccionario del español actual*, en el de mexicanismos de la Academia Mexicana de la Lengua y en el *Diccionario de uso del español*, de María Moliner, que ya en su primera edición señalaba que se empleaba con el sentido de ‘extravagante, sorprendente o gracioso’.

Es decir, que parece que la RAE se queda sola en su defensa del significado original de la palabra. Merece la pena hacer mención a este comentario, extraído de [un artículo](https://verne.elpais.com/verne/2015/11/05/articulo/1446740407_989364.html) del blog *Verne*, del diario *El País*:

> Y ya lo siento, pero si usamos 'bizarro' únicamente para decir "bizarro significa raro y no valiente", no hay más remedio que admitir que la batalla está perdida.

Curiosamente, el final del artículo coincide con lo que afirmaba en la respuesta antes de la actualización:

> Es decir, es posible que la RAE acabe admitiendo una tercera acepción de bizarro y aceptando que también significa raro porque, al fin y al cabo, así es como la mayoría lo usa. [...] Es cierto que se trata de un error, de un calco censurable, pero la función principal del diccionario es descriptiva, es decir, recoge cómo hablamos.

---

**[Actualización 2020]** Parece que definitivamente la RAE da la batalla por perdida. A fin de cuentas, su labor es registrar el uso que la gente hace del lenguaje. Recientemente en [un tuit](https://mobile.twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/1294575868795326464) han escrito lo siguiente:

> Consultas de la semana | ¿Se puede usar «bizarro» con el significado
> de ‘raro’?
>
> Aunque tradicionalmente «bizarro» se ha usado para ‘valiente,
> aguerrido’ o ‘lucido, airoso’, hoy es normal su uso como ‘raro,
> extravagante’, sentido cuya incorporación al «DLE» está prevista.

Por tanto, está claro que la inclusión de la nueva acepción (que zanjará definitivamente todo debate al respecto) es solo cuestión de tiempo.

---

**[Actualización 2021]** La RAE finalmente ha admitido la acepción en el DLE:

> **[bizarro, rra](https://dle.rae.es/bizarro)**
>
> Del it. *bizzarro* 'iracundo'.
>
> 1. adj. valiente (‖ arriesgado).
> 2. adj. Generoso, lucido, espléndido.
> 3. adj. Raro, extravagante o fuera de lo común.

Comment: En alemán "bizarr" también significa raro/estrafalario.

Comment: Aunque el artículo de Verne me parece bastante bueno, creo que el autor ha cometido un desliz justamente en la frase que citas. Imagino que quiere decir *si usamos 'bizarro' únicamente para decir "bizarro significa valiente y no raro", no hay más remedio...*

Comment: Siguen dándose pasos hacia la aceptación del término. La RAE [tuiteó recientemente](https://mobile.twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/1294575868795326464): _Aunque tradicionalmente «bizarro» se ha usado para ‘valiente, aguerrido’ o ‘lucido, airoso’, hoy es normal su uso como ‘raro, extravagante’, sentido cuya incorporación al «DLE» está prevista_

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' ¡Gracias por el aviso! He modificado la respuesta para añadir esta información, la segunda actualización ya en esta historia que va para cuatro años. :-)

Comment: Es bonito ver que el sitio ya es un "vídeo" (cortito, pero vídeo) de la lengua y ya podemos ver el histórico de su evolución en base a cosas que hemos vivido.

Comment: La actualización que acabas de añadir a esta respuesta me parece realmente interesante, Charlie (gracias @fedorqui'SOstopharming' por el aviso). A propósito, el diccionario italiano que has usado creo (por algún comentario que he leído) que no goza de demasiada reputación (o, en todo caso, no se sabe muy bien quién y cómo se ha elaborado). En este [post](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/123/) encontrarás una lista de diccionarios que se consideran más fiables.

Comment: @Charo ¡gracias! Cuando escribí la respuesta en su día creo que no llevaba mucho tiempo por aquí, supongo que simplemente busqué en Google y me salió ese diccionario. ^__^U Ahora suelo tener más cuidado con los diccionario que elijo para cada idioma.

Answer (score 12):

Sí, al menos en el habla culta de Argentina, la palabra *bizarro* se usa exclusivamente con el sentido de *extravagante, estrafalario, insólito*.

Se usa particularmente en la crítica de arte: teatro, cine, televisión, literatura.

De todas maneras, la equivalencia con *bizarre* del inglés no es exacta. Podríamos decir que de alguna manera la versión Argentina es más "fuerte":  para que se aplique tiene que tratarse de algo más extraño que su contraparte inglesa.

Esta cita, que encontré [aquí](http://hispanoteca.eu/Foro-preguntas/ARCHIVO-Foro/bizarro%20no%20es%20lo%20mismo%20que%20%20bizarre.htm), muestra que la palabra se usa con este sentido en Argentina desde hace al menos cuarenta años:

> «Bizarro: El francés *bizarre* no equivale exactamente a *bizarro*, sino a *extravagante*. El significado tradicional del español *bizarro* es ‘valiente’: *Una gran parte de los intelectuales argentinos lo calificaron [a Borges] de bizarro (en el sentido francés de la palabra), de extravagante, de marginal y separado* (Revista *Destino*, 6.1.1973, 7).»

[Seco, Manuel: Diccionario de dudas y dificultades de la lengua española. Madrid: Espasa-Calpe, 1998, p. 82]

Que el DRAE no recoja el uso de esta acepción en Argentina, es como mínimo una omisión.

En cuanto al ejemplo que pones, no hay duda de que en Argentina un elefante saliendo del baúl de un auto sería una situación muy bizarra.

Aquí hay algunos ejemplos del uso de *bizarro* en la prensa:

- [Jorge Fernández Díaz: "Lo de Guillermo Moreno fue bizarro y vergonzoso"](http://www.lanacion.com.ar/1906287-jorge-fernandez-diaz-lo-de-guillermo-moreno-fue-bizarro-y-vergonzoso)
- [El nuevo spot bizarro de Jorge Altamira](http://www.lanacion.com.ar/1806943-el-nuevo-spot-bizarro-de-jorge-altamira)
- [El hallazgo más bizarro durante allanamiento a las propiedades de Báez: una costosa estatua de Néstor](http://www.eltrecetv.com.ar/telenoche/el-hallazgo-mas-bizarro-durante-allanamiento-a-las-propiedades-de-baez-una_085935)
- [Bizarro diálogo entre el esposo de Mónica López y Nancy Pazos](http://www.clarin.com/politica/Roberti-Monica_Lopez-Pazos-massismo-sciolismo-sexo_0_1441656049.html)
- [Bizarro: expulsó a un comentarista](http://www.ole.com.ar/fuera-de-juego/Bizarro-arbitro-expulso-comentarista-Tv_0_1468653431.html)
- [El bizarro velorio en Puerto Rico que causa polémica](http://www.larazon.com.ar/interesa/bizarro-velorio-Puerto-Rico-polemica_0_726600178.html)

Y es significativa [esta sinopsis](http://www.encuentro.gov.ar/sitios/encuentro/programas/ver?rec_id=125798) de un programa emitido por un canal de argentina:

> Hay personajes que llevan adelante un belicismo poético. Tomando el concepto de bizarro del castellano original, que no refiere a lo ridículo, sino al coraje, a la generosidad y al altruismo, vida y hazañas de hombres y mujeres que no gozaron de un lugar galardonado en los libros de historia, pero participaron de muchos de sus acontecimientos.

Es decir, que si en Argentina uno quiere usar la palabra *bizarro* en el sentido que le da la RAE, debe aclararlo explícitamente o será malentendido.

Comment: Fantástica respuesta. Me parece que la frase final podría aplicarse a todas las regiones: _Si uno quiere usar la palabra bizarro en el sentido que le da la RAE, debe aclararlo explícitamente o será malentendido_. No creo que tarde demasiado en aceptarse, pues tal y como dice [la página](http://verne.elpais.com/verne/2015/11/05/articulo/1446740407_989364.html) que enlaza Daniel Parejo en su respuesta: _solo se utiliza de forma correcta en frases que corrigen su mal uso_.

Answer (score 4):

*¿Que bizarro significa "valiente"?* ¡Eso sí que es *bizarro*!

Me considero una persona culta y con amplio vocabulario, y creo haber utilizado la palabra *bizarro* en ese sentido desde que tengo uso de razón, (¿quizá por haberla aprendido de libros mal traducidos?), y por lo que veo [no soy el único](http://verne.elpais.com/verne/2015/11/05/articulo/1446740407_989364.html), ergo... no es algo tan raro.

Normalmente en estos casos suelo corregirme de inmediato y evitar el uso erróneo, pero la verdad es que en este caso, no pienso hacerlo. Suena natural. Y si mi actitud os parece *bizarra*... ¡pues eso que me llevo!

PD: Además, si en el resto de idiomas mayoritarios de nuestro continente significa "raro", ¡más motivo aún para incluir esa acepción! ¡"*Hace europeo*"!

Comment: Que no pienses dejar de usar esa palabra no la hace correcta. Asimismo, que uses palabras con significados no reconocidos por la DRAE tampoco es un crimen. Probablemente esta palabra sea añadida en un futuro, pero hasta entonces seguirá teniendo ese único significado (tan bizarro)

Comment: Desde luego, vive aun en esa zona gris intermedia, luego  creo que "no esta reconocido oficialmente pero puedes usarlo" es una respuesta viable a la pregunta del OP :)

Comment: Pues en mi experiencia, el significado que más he leido de "bizarro" es "valiente", "arrojado". Su significado como "extraño o extravagante" es algo muy reciente, y por malas traducciones del inglés. Y sí, coincido con Ra_ en el primer comentario a la pregunta en que no es ni más ni menos que otro "falso amigo".

Comment: @mcleod_ideafix tu experiencia y la mia difieren diametralmente, obviamente. Debe ser una cuestión de edad o geografía (en mi caso, sureste de España, nacido en los 80). Curioso, cuanto menos... :)

Comment: En mi caso, suroeste de España, nacido en los 70.

Answer (score 1):

Estimated reading time: 15 minutes.

No TL;DR, but my short answer to your question is this:

### Yes (the translation of "bizarro" is "bizarre"), and often, and in many different places, but not yet officially sanctioned.

---

### What led me to this post

Though a few answers have been provided and the green check mark awarded, I'm going to add another answer because I think I have some additional details that may be useful to those who happen to stumble upon this thread ... especially those whose Spanish may not be that good and who don't have an easy way to translate some of the other answers into English.  Please note, however, that this will not be a rehash in English of what others have written in Spanish.

To be perfectly honest, I never really thought much about this word "**bizarro**" until I came across this Facebook post here:

[image]
*From the Facebook page "[**Gramática Real**](https://www.facebook.com/GramaticaReal/posts/1213330222177230)."  Posted April 1, 2019, 7:36 p.m.  Retrieved April 1, 2019, o/a 9:30 p.m.  FTR, "bizarro" can mean, according to no less an authority than the dictionary of the Royal Spanish Academy, "**lucido**," which means "splendid" or "magnificent."  It does not mean "lucid."  The word "lucid" is "lúcido" in Spanish.*

Ordinarily, I might have just quickly read it and continued scrolling, but the addition of "serious mistake" compelled me to take a closer look at this word.

### Frequency

If you're a beginning student of Spanish, I should let you know up front that "bizarro" is not likely to come up very frequently in the Spanish literature you may or may not be reading yet.  According to one frequency list, **"bizarro" is ranked #22334.**  You're more likely to encounter "malvaviscos" (marshmallows), "acordeón" (accordion), and "oruga" (caterpillar) than you are "bizarro."

All discussion of what the real meaning of "bizarro" is aside, if you're looking for a way to translate "bizarre" into Spanish, you'll find many better options, some of which can be seen in the Google Ngram below.  These include (in order of semantic proximity according to synonyms listed [**here**](https://synonyms.reverso.net/synonym/es/bizarro)): ***raro, extraño, peculiar, estrafalario, inusual***.  If you want to link directly to the Google Ngram itself, click [**here**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bizarro%2Craro%2Cextra%C3%B1o%2Cpeculiar%2Cestrafalario%2Cinusual&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=10&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbizarro%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Craro%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cextra%C3%B1o%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpeculiar%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cestrafalario%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinusual%3B%2Cc0).

[image]

Your question is posed in a way that leaves room open for answering from a historical perspective, but Charlie (who has also provided an answer in this thread) succinctly, yet thoroughly answers from more of a historic perspective in this answer [**here**](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/28504/why-bizarre-english-and-bizarro-spanish-have-different-meanings/28515#28515).  So, I will try to limit my answer to much more modern usage — the last 40 years or so.

### CREA Findings

One of the first things I did to try to answer your question (after taking a look at the Google Ngram), was search the [**Corpus de Referencia del Español Actual (CREA)**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corpus_de_Referencia_del_Espa%C3%B1ol_Actual).

To attempt to prove that a word is never used in a certain way is akin to attempting to [**prove a negative**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proving_a_negative), so I don't know, at this point, if I'll be able to say, by the end of this answer, that "bizarro" is never used to mean "bizarre."  My hunch, initially, was that it would be highly unlikely and that if you did see it used in that way, you just might want to consider the quality or origin of the source.  For starters, was it written by a native speaker of Spanish?  Is it a translation?  Is the publication a reputable one?  Although the answers to those questions may factor in to why you might see "bizarro" used to mean "bizarre," I don't know that they fully explain all instances you may see of "bizarro" when clearly the meaning is "bizarre."  But I'll get to those examples in a bit.  For now, let me first show you a couple of **examples of "bizarro" that CREA led me to.**  Where possible, I will try to find the full version of the source.  Here's the first example I've selected for you:

> Y siendo ya un adulto Hera lo reconoce y enloquece, a consecuencia de lo cual empieza un largo peregrinar acompañado de su tutor, Sileno, y de Sátiros y Ménades. Es entonces cuando empieza a constituir su **bizarro** ejército, el cual dirige armado de un tirso cubierto de yedra y con una piña de pino en la punta.
>
> — "[Detener la guerra](http://www.ufg.edu.sv/ufg/theorethikos/Enero02/detener_la_guerra.html#1)," *Theorethikos*.
>
> *And being an adult Hera recognizes him and goes mad, the result of which begins a long pilgrimage accompanied by his tutor, Silenus, and Satyrs and Maenads. It is then when he begins to form his **gallant** army, which he leads armed with a sceptre covered with ivy and tipped with a pine cone.*

---

*All translations from Spanish into English were made by me, the author of this answer, with a little help from the translator embedded in Google Chrome.*

---

> Al mismo tiempo la película mantiene ese estilo morboso, crudo y repugnante (en cuanto a los materiales que se usan en la historia) característico de Cronenberg, que hace que la realidad se vea cada vez más borrosa (¿será toda la película un gran juego **bizarro** o se trata de una realidad bizarra?).
>
> — Film [on line], 06-07/2003 : El elefante y la bicicleta
>
> [Citation format is direct copy from CREA, which indicates this publication is Argentinian.  Excerpt actually appears to be a film review of the film *Existenz*.]
>
> *At the same time, the film maintains that morbid, raw, and repugnant style (in terms of the materials used in the story) characteristic of Cronenberg, which makes reality look more and more blurred (will the whole movie be a big **bizarre** game or is it a bizarre reality?).*

**In the first example, clearly, the meaning of "bizarro" is not "bizarre"; in the second, it is.**  But bear in mind the fact that the second example is from an Argentinian publication.  [Please read  rsanchez's answer and you'll see that this example supports what s/he has written.]

In the examples provided by CREA, I couldn't always determine whether or not a simple "brave" or "bizarre" was the best translation.  In at least a couple of situations, "gallant" might have been a better translation than "brave" and "extravagant" a better translation than "bizarre."  That said, what I could more or less definitively translate can be seen in the chart below:

[image]
*If any of you saw the previous table, you will see that the table now has a lot more examples.  And, in fact, the previous table made it look as if "bizarro" more often meant "bizarre" than "brave."  A more thorough look reveals that this isn't necessarily true (at least not in the examples provided by CREA).  Still, a significant number of examples do show that "bizarro" has been used to mean "bizarre" and at least as far back as 1981.  Furthermore, if you take a look at just those examples from the year 2000 and beyond, less than a fifth are examples of "bizarro" as "brave," but more than half are examples of "bizarro" as "bizarre."*

### Beyond CREA

Having said that, I noticed early on that I was having difficulty finding examples of “bizarro” used as “brave” outside of CREA.  At first I thought I just wasn’t looking closely enough and was going to leave it at that, but curiosity got the better of me and I decided to take a closer look. The chart below is a synthesis of what I found:

[image]

As you can see, I found it very difficult to find examples where “bizarro” was used to mean “brave.”  On occasion, I encountered an article that made me think the translation could go either way … for example is [**a chef with an adventurous appetite for disgusting food**](https://www.semana.com/gente/articulo/andrew-zimmern-un-hombre-bizarro/375785-3) "bizarre," or "brave," or maybe both all at once?  I also realized, after seeing this article [**here**](https://tn.com.ar/musica/clips/el-bizarro-coro-militar-ruso-que-hace-covers-de-canciones-en-ingles_418326), that I couldn’t always assume that “bizarre” always meant “brave” when referring to something related to the military.

Another answer in this thread lists some **examples from headlines**, so I won’t clutter up this thread with the list I started to collect as I began studying this word “bizarro” more thoroughly, but, if you’d like, you can view it [**here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7l1O.jpg).  It isn’t a complete list.  In other words, it doesn’t contain everything I looked at to produce the chart above, but it contains the type of example (e.g., headline or book*), name of the newspaper or title of the book, country, year, and meaning.  If you take a look at it, you’ll see that it was much more common to find “bizarre” used as “brave” in books, but, even so, those examples I found typically reference texts or events in history that go back decades if not centuries ago.  Now that I think about it, I don’t think I found even one example where “bizarre” was used as “brave” to refer to something current.

---

**Initially I was going to do a similar chart for books, but the data set that was returned was so small, it seemed ridiculous to include it.  Later, I did wind up making a couple of charts for what I found in books, but please read the notes at the bottom of these charts if you do.  Truth be told, I have a feeling that there exists more publications with "bizarro" in them than what Google's Ngram and Google's Book search returned for me, but I don't know that the results would be all that different.*

*To sum them up, "bizarro" as "bizarre" is found in more recent publications; "bizarro" as "brave" is found in older ones.  As for popular culture, more recent publications make reference to the supervillian known as "Bizarro" but, rather bizarrely, none make reference to the band "Triángulo de Amor Bizarro," despite its prominence in news headlines during the last couple of decades.  (If it's true that no books have been written about this band, what a missed marketing opportunity!)*

*Like I mentioned, the data sets are small for these charts, but if you want to take a look at them, you can find the one created from Google Ngram results [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bxSw.jpg), and the one from a Google Books search [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Hem0.jpg).  Keep in mind that I was restricted to those books that either via preview or snippet allowed me to see "bizarro" in context.*

---

As for location, it runs the gamut, but Spain seems to dominate, followed by Argentina and Mexico.  A lot of headlines referred to the Galician band Triángulo de Amor Bizarro and because of that, Spain comes up quite a bit.

This examination of the headlines of online news articles (and books) clearly indicates that **"bizarro" is being used to mean "bizarre."**  In fact, you’re far more likely to find examples where "bizarro" is used to mean "bizarre" than examples where "bizarro" means "brave," "gallant," or "generous."

At any rate, all of this certainly supports what was written in the Facebook post I came across, which claimed (right or wrong) that “bizarro” is more often used to mean “bizarre” than “brave.”

### Collocations

To continue showing examples of how "bizarro" is used to mean "bizarre," take a look at the following [**collocations**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collocation) I found for "bizarro":

**cine bizarro

mundo bizarro

bizarro versión

comportamiento bizarro

humor bizarro**

I find it difficult to believe that "gallant," "brave," or "generous" are meant in any of [**the above collocations**](http://www.linguatools.de/kollokationen-es/bolls/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=bizarro&commit=Search+Collocations%21).

### What does the Academy say?

For those of you who don't know, it is no easy task to maintain standards and consistency in a language that is spoken in at least 20 different countries.  That the Spanish spoken in Mexico is the same Spanish that can be understood by those who live in Spain is no accident.  It is through the concerted efforts of institutions such as the [**Royal Spanish Academy [Real Academia Española (RAE)]**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Spanish_Academy) that standards of the language are maintained.

One of the ways in which this is accomplished is via judicious administration of the [***Diccionario de la Real Academia Española (DRAE)***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diccionario_de_la_lengua_espa%C3%B1ola).  Words and meanings added to this dictionary are not added on a whim.  Decisions on what should be added and what should be removed are not made lightly.  However, [**at least as far back as 2010**](https://www.revistaarcadia.com/periodismo-cultural-revista-arcadia/ideas/articulo/palabras-mal-usadas-del-idioma-espanol/22970), this disconnect between the world’s most preeminent Spanish dictionary and actual usage has been noted.  Despite any attempts to add "bizarre" to the meaning of "bizarro," the *DRAE* entry still looks like this:

[image]

despite headlines like this:

**"[Por fin puedes usar 'bizarro' para decir "raro](https://verne.elpais.com/verne/2016/11/10/articulo/1478780253_802615.html)"**

but perhaps it is just a matter of time before we see it added to the *DRAE*.

### Online Dictionaries

In the meantime, you can find "bizarro" translated as "bizarre" in online dictionaries such as [**Tureng**](https://termbank.com/en/spanish-english/bizarro), [**Wiktionary**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bizarro#Spanish), and [**PONS**](https://en.pons.com/translate?q=bizarro&l=enes&in=&lf=es), but both Tureng and Wiktionary seem to think that only certain Spanish speakers are using it to mean this, namely those Spanish speakers in Argentina, Chile, as well as Puerto Rico (if you extend the meaning to "weird").  It appears that [**Collins**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/spanish-english/bizarro) and [**WordReference**](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=bizarro) may be holding out until the RAE makes the change.

Oddly enough, a search of [**"bizarro" via Reverso's context dictionary**](https://context.reverso.net/translation/spanish-english/bizarro) doesn't even list "brave" or any of the other definitions, but, and I suppose this is a bit *bizarre*, [**its dictionary**](https://dictionary.reverso.net/spanish-english/bizarro) (technically Collins), *does* list "gallant" and "brave" as primary meanings and "generous" as a secondary meaning.

### Commentary on “bizarro” as “bizarre”: Advising against it, acknowledging it, accepting it

For your situational awareness, it appears that as late as 2005, reputable publications such as the [***Diccionario panhispánico de dudas***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diccionario_panhisp%C3%A1nico_de_dudas) (and more recently [**others**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upgbl.jpg)) were advising against the use of "bizarro" as a word for conveying "extraño" (strange) or "extravagante" (extravagant), which is what the word "bizarre" can mean in both French and English.  You can read more along these lines [**here**](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?bizarro).  In it, you will find that one contributor has written:

> **... puede llegar un momento en que [el uso de "bizarro" como "bizarre"] sea general y se vean obligadas a aceptarlo.**

Something veteran journalist (and professor) Graciela Melgarejo of *La Nación* echoes with this:

> Por el tiempo transcurrido y la presencia cada vez más frecuente, hasta en diccionarios, esta acepción "extraña" de bizarro se va imponiendo a la de "Mi Bandera". Habrá que seguir el proceso de legitimización, si es que llega.
>
> — “[**Entre bazares y vasares, una actitud ejemplar**](https://www.lanacion.com.ar/opinion/entre-bazares-y-vasares-una-actitud-ejemplar-nid1670712)”, *La Nación*

But in more recent times, oh, say, the last five years or so, reputable publications have been brave enough to flat out go against the grain of convention and explicitly state that "bizarro" has two meanings.  In addition to the article I already provided a link to — Por fin puedes usar 'bizarro' para decir "raro" — you'll find these:

> La palabra bizarro tiene dos acepciones. Una ... se refiere a una persona extraña, peculiar o extravagante. Otra ... quiere decir valiente.
>
> — "[**El mundo bizarro de Andrés Manuel**](https://www.elfinanciero.com.mx/opinion/raymundo-riva-palacio/el-mundo-bizarro-de-andres-manuel)", *El Financiero* (2019)
>
> ... el uso de "bizarro" con equivalencia a "valiente" o "gallardo" ya prácticamente nadie lo usa ...
>
> — "[**57. bizarro: ¿extraño?, ¿extravagante?, ¿gallardo?, ¿ridículo?, ¿valiente?**](https://books.google.es/books?id=4H1TDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT105&dq=%22bizarro%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjpm6Wh7bnhAhWrVN8KHS13AfU4ChDoAQg4MAI#v=onepage&q=%22bizarro%22%20con%20equivalencia%20a&f=false)" *Las malas lenguas: Barbarismos, desbarres, palabros, redundancias, sinsentidos y demás barrabasadas*, by [**Juan Domingo Argüelles**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juan_Domingo_Arg%C3%BCelles) (2018)
>
> Aunque parezca difícil de creer, la palabra "bizarro" no significa "raro", sino que funciona como un sinónimo de "valiente", "iracundo" o incluso "espléndido".  Sin embargo, la Fundación de Español Urgente (Fundéu), organización que se encarga de velar por el correcto uso del idioma español, ha habilitado finalmente su uso para este propósito.
>
> — "[**Ahora la palabra 'bizarro' se puede utilizar para decir 'raro'"**](https://www.elobservador.com.uy/nota/ahora-la-palabra-bizarro-se-puede-utilizar-para-decir-raro--2016111411300), *El Observador* (2016)

Others don't refer to its meaning as "brave" at all because, I'm assuming, in certain fields, its meaning as "brave" simply has no place contextually.  For example:

> **BIZARRO.**  Adjetivo formado del español *bizarro*, *bravo*, con influencia semántica del francés *bigazarré*, abigarrado.
>
> — "[**Bizarro**](https://books.google.es/books?id=Z9rH7cPw-yoC&pg=PA197&dq=%22bizarro%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjzhfC_1bnhAhURnOAKHVnMAIEQ6AEIODAC#v=onepage&q=%22bizarro%22&f=false)".  *Diccionario Akal de Estética*
>
> *The work briefly cited above was actually written by Étienne Souriau, a French philosopher best known for his work in aesthetics.  I suppose this may have also contributed to the absence of any mention of "bizarro" as "brave," but the Spanish version of this book was published in 1998 by [**Ediciones Akal**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ediciones_Akal), a Spanish publisher based in Madrid.*

### Popular Culture

In addition to all of that, there exists some prominent uses of "bizarro" as "bizarre" in popular culture.  Besides the nefarious character of DC Comics fame known as "Bizarro," there is also the Galician band "[**Triángulo de Amor Bizarro**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tri%C3%A1ngulo_de_Amor_Bizarro)," and a Six Flags roller coaster called "Bizarro."

The first two definitely carry with them the meaning of "bizarre."  (In fact, the band "Triángulo de Amor Bizarro" took its name from a song by the British rock band New Order — "[**Bizarre Love Triangle**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7uEBuqkkQRk).")  The theme of the roller coaster is that of the DC Comics supervillain, but I suppose one could make a case that you need to be "brave" to ride it, something of a moot point since you aren't likely to find a Six Flags in any Spanish-speaking country.

In addition to that, [**“bizarro” is also a genre of fiction writing**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bizarro_fiction), as well as a genre of film, the type that is described by some as “[**un subgénero cinematográfico de películas surrealistas, de terror e incluso …**](https://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/el-erroneo-uso-que-se-hace-en-castellano-del-termino-bizarro/).”

So, clearly, there are a multitude of ways in which “bizarro” as a word used to reference the “bizarre” may be creeping into and out of the Spanish language.

---

Initially, I thought that the use of "bizarro" to mean "bizarre" or "extravagant" rather than "brave," "generous," "splendid," "magnificent," or "lavish," could be as high as 3:1 and that may have been true at one point in time, but when I took the time to dig a little deeper, it clearly does not seem to be the case now.  (In other words, the ratio seems to be much higher.)  In fact, you’ll have a hard time finding examples where “bizarro” is used to mean “brave” or any of the other definitions listed in the *DRAE*.  Furthermore, this use appears to be present from Mexico to Argentina and a lot of countries in between (not to mention Spain itself).  Consequently, and with no disrespect to the Royal Spanish Academy and its decision-making process, I think the time for adding "bizarre" as a meaning of "bizarro" is long overdue and its absence is something that many, quite frankly, find bizarre.

---

*Correction: Thanks to fedorqui, I now know that the Spanish dictionary produced, edited, and published by the Royal Spanish Academy (RAE) is now referred to as the* [**Diccionario de la lengua española**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diccionario_de_la_lengua_espa%C3%B1ola) *or the* DLE.  *Up until the 23rd edition of this dictionary, which was published in 2014, it was called the* Diccionario de la Real Academia Española *or the* DRAE.  *A lot of people, Spanish natives and nonnatives alike, may not know this, so you may still see references to the* DRAE, *but whether you see* DRAE *or* DLE, *know that both are referring to the dictionary governed by the RAE.*

Comment: @Potter-Pirbright Sí.  Inicialmente mi respuesta fue una semilla, pero ahora es una planta.  Cambié el tiempo de lectura.  Debería ser un poco más razonable ahora.

Comment: This is a great piece of work! Thanks for the TL;DR on top of it, since normally such long answers are not that easy to digest. I added a couple of links to the sources you were using. I hope I can get some free time to read it in one shot. Many thanks for your efforts to write such comprehensive answers, Lisa! And, if possible, could you try to post the answers in their almost final version? Not to bump the post so many times in the front page of the site. Thanks!

Comment: @fedorqui Is that what's happening?  Sorry, didn't know.  The thing is, I never intend to make so many additional edits.  With this one, I had thought I had made the final edit quite some time ago and had set it aside for what I thought was the last time when a bolt of inspiration hit me.  Is there any way to keep an answer from bumping to the front page of a site?  Or somehow muting it?

Comment: @fedorqui Also, sorry for rolling back your edit.  It's just that I discovered I used an acronym without proper antecedence and I can't assume that everyone knows what that acronym is.  Unfortunately, the system told me my edit needed to be more substantial than the one you made in order to let me do it.  I could have let it stand as is, but it's a standard I try to adhere to.  Plus, a dearly departed mentor of mine, who never failed to question any stand-alone acronym, would be disappointed.  I see the edit you made, however.  It's a good idea.  I'll add it back in.

Comment: @LisaBeck mmm not that I know. [Many things bump questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48579/209901) :) The thing is that moderators receive an automatic flag when someone is posting over 20 times, and this happened some times already. It is not important and we know it is for good, so it is just a tool we get from the system to notice potential weird cases. You can maybe use external tools to draft your posts, there are some that admit markdown, so you can see how it looks so far.

Comment: No problem with the rollback! It was quite minor, just a couple of links and the thing that we call it DLE, not DRAE (DLE = Diccionario de la Lengua Española).

Comment: @fedorqui Well, well, well!  I learn something new every day.  Thank you for correcting me on my use of DRAE.  (That's what YouTube learning from non-natives will get 'ya.)  I suppose this is sloppy/lazy on my part, but do you mind if I just leave it as is?  Truth be told, I was going to change it to DLE, but then I thought about all of the other times I've used DRAE and then I took a look at how many others have, too.  (There's more than 2,000 answers that use DRAE instead of DLE!  Who knew?  I guess we didn't.)  In the future, though, I will use DLE.  Again, thank you.

Comment: Lisa as I said some comments before: please try to avoid so many edits, since it keeps bumping the question over and over again. There are places where you can draft some markdown and then post it here. Many thanks

Comment: I'm done. TY4 allowing me to put some finishing touches on it. Also, FTR, though Spanish SE has >2,000 threads w/DRAE, TBT, there's been <200 since the 23rd ed. was released (if the release/pub. date was 11/4/2014).  & while I'm at it, since I have a few characters left, TY4 the compliments and the professionalism. You're one of SE's best moderators (and best contributors). Wanna know s.th. funny? When I first started answering this question, I didn't notice who'd asked it. Thought it was just some random Joe. When I realized it was you, I thought to myself _Now I have to make it good._