# ¿Es correcto usar "condescender" para hablar de tratar a alguien con superioridad?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, inglés, préstamo-lingüístico

El DLE nos define *condescender* como:

> [**condescender**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ABa92po)
>   Del lat. *condescendĕre*.
>   1. intr. Acomodarse por bondad al gusto y voluntad de alguien.

Sin embargo, cada vez más lo veo utilizado en un sentido diferente:

> — Cuando le pregunté, el profesor me respondió de una forma muy condescendiente: me trató de ignorante de una forma sutil, desdeñando mis argumentos con medias verdades.

En [una discusión](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2784/83) en Meta de Stack Overflow en español mencionan que este uso es un calco del inglés [*condescendence*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/condescend?s=t):

> 1. to behave as if one is conscious of descending from a superior position, rank, or dignity.

Mirando en [Word Reference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=condescend) veo que traducen *condescende* como *condescender*, por lo que parecería que el término es correcto, pero como traducción de la tercera acepcíon del inglés:

> 3. to put aside one's dignity or superiority voluntarily and assume equality with one regarded as inferior.

Tal y como vimos con [¿Es "eventualmente" una traducción válida de "eventually"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/16380/1674) y [¿Es "bizarro" en algún caso la traducción de "bizarre"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17074/1674), parecería que se está extendiendo el uso de *condescender* como falsa traducción de un término que probablemente ya existe, por lo que me surgen dos dudas:

- ¿Es correcto usar *condescender* para hablar de la acción de tratar a alguien con superioridad?
- Si no es así, ¿cuál sería la traducción correcta de *condescendence*?

Comment: Se me hace tan correcto como "hace sentido". Es usar el significado del otro idioma desconociendo el significado/uso que las palabras tiene en español.

Comment: Pareciera que, más allá de posible interferencia con el inglés, esto es un típico proceso de peyoración. (Algo parecido pasa con la expresión *dignarse a hacer algo*.)

Comment: ¿*Calco del inglés* quiere decir *equivalente*?

Comment: Aparte de que si se encuentra la acepción deseada en un diccionario, está el aspecto, si se va a entender así en conversación.  Sospecho que no, y sería mejor decir por ejemplo *trato altivo*.

Comment: @aparente001 sería lo que [mencionó blonfu](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/22294/1674) de _calco semántico_. Un "false friend", vaya :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A la definición de la RAE lo único que le sobra es lo de "con bondad".

**Condescender** es, efectivamente, acomodarse al gusto de alguien, ponerse a su nivel, normalmente inferior; de ahí lo de "-descender".
También puede inferirse esta connotación de "inferior" a partir del uso de "acomodarse", que implica que quien condesciende está pasando, desde su punto de vista, a un nivel más cómodo: uno que le resulta más sencillo, que no requiere de toda su capacidad.

**Condescendiente** es quien hace lo anterior. Puede ser un padre hablando con su hijo, o un maestro con su aprendiz:

> Tienes que ser más **condescendiente** con el chaval, que está aprendiendo.

No hay nada negativo en ser *condescendiente* de esa manera. Pero sí en esta otra:

> ¿Pues no que llega ayer el becario y se pone a explicarme *con aire **condescendiente*** cómo exportar un informe? ¡Si el módulo de informes lo he diseñado yo!

Aquí lo que pasa es que **cuando alguien es *condescendiente* de forma ostensible**, dejando claro que considera que se está rebajando a un nivel inferior, **resulta ofensivo, especialmente si la otra persona NO se considera inferior** ni necesitada de condescendencia.
Es entonces cuando acusamos, de manera negativa, de ser condescendiente. Pero no es porque condescendiente tenga otro significado negativo aparte del que ya tiene; es porque no siempre es cierto que se haga "con bondad".

Por eso digo, que bastaría con quitar ese "con bondad" de la definición, y dejar que sean el contexto y los hablantes quienes hagan ese juicio.

Comment: Yo lo de "acomodarse a los deseos de otro" no lo veo como bajar de nivel, sino adaptarse o ceder. Si voy a un concierto con un amigo en lugar de al cine como yo quería, me acomodo a su gusto, no bajo de nivel. Aún sin el "con bondad" no veo igual decir *acomodarse* que *rebajarse*, creo que el DLE tendría que cambiar algo más en esa definición para que sirviera en todos los casos.

Comment: Yo no usaría la palabra *condescender* tampoco para eso  pero creo que según la definición del DRAE sí podría hacerlo.

Comment: Lo que me alucina es un ejemplo del DPD para cuando significa _acomodarse **voluntariamente** a los deseos de otro_ (aquí no usa bondad): _«Se ve obligado a condescender con el gusto del enfermo o a perder la casa»_ No sé que ven ahí de voluntario

Answer (score 5):

Resulta muy curioso que, aunque el DLE recoge para "condescender" un único significado, [el DPD recoge tres](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=condescender):

- "acomodarse voluntariamente a los deseos de otro" (la del DLE),
- "rebajarse a hacer algo que se considera indigno o humillante", y
- "ser condescendiente o tolerante con algo".

En el caso de estos dos últimos ejemplos, cita respectivamente:

> «Los filósofos condescienden a interesarse por la muerte para minimizarla o certificar su inexistencia» (Savater Invitación [Esp. 1982]).
>
> «La democracia, más aún cuando es frágil e imperfecta, no puede darse el lujo de condescender con actitudes y actos que la ponen en grave riesgo» (Proceso [Méx.] 15.9.96).

El segundo significado implica un tono negativo: te estás rebajando a hacer algo que consideras indigno. Luego en la frase del ejemplo que planteas, se puede considerar que el profesor "se rebajó a responder a otra persona a la que considera ignorante". En todo caso, sí que es cierto que el significado inglés es ligeramente diferente: no es lo mismo "rebajarse a hacer algo que consideras indigno" a "hacer sentir al otro que eres superior". Podría ser el caso si la persona que considera que se está rebajando expresa ese sentimiento y lo hace ver a su interlocutor. En ese caso este se podría sentir como que no es digno (y por tanto sentirse inferior).

En ningún caso el DPD considera que alguno de estos tres sentidos sea incorrecto o esté desaconsejado. Luego entiendo que el uso es correcto, aunque este significado como tal no aparezca en el DLE (tal vez haya que preguntarle a la RAE el porqué). La diferencia entre el significado inglés y la segunda acepción del DPD se podría llegar a considerar inexistente, es una simple cuestión de la actitud del que condesciende.

Comment: Tal cual. Seguramente lo hemos comentado en otras ocasiones, pero no lo recuerdo: ¿quién incorpora antes los cambios, el DPD o el DLE?

Comment: @fedorqui no encuentro ninguna pregunta al respecto en el sitio...

Comment: La diferencia está en que en inglés la persona usualmente no se "rebaja a hacer lo que considera indigno" sino que hace que la otra persona se sienta inferior. En realidad casi siempre se usa cuando una persona hace sentir inferior a otra y carece de "tolerancia" (3er significado).

Comment: @DGaleano he añadido una pequeña explicación al respecto.

Answer (score 3):

En el DLE solo aparece una acepción para condescender:

> [**condescender**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ABa92po)
>
> 1. intr. Acomodarse por bondad al gusto y voluntad de alguien.

Sin embargo en el [DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=condescender) hay una entrada sobre condescender que nos da más significados:

> **2.** Cuando significa ‘acomodarse voluntariamente a los deseos de otro’(...)
>   **3.** Cuando significa ‘rebajarse a hacer algo que se considera indigno o humillante’(...)
>   **4.** Cuando significa ‘ser condescendiente o tolerante con algo’(...)

La acepción del punto 3 podría usarse con el significado de:

> *to behave as if one is conscious of descending from a superior
>   position, rank, or dignity.*

Y la del punto 4 con:

> *to put aside one's dignity or superiority voluntarily and assume
>   equality with one regarded as inferior.*

Answer (score 3):

Pongo en una respuesta aparte lo que me ha comentado la RAE al respecto. Os muestro primero la carta que les envié, y luego su respuesta.

> En nuestro sitio de preguntas y respuestas sobre el idioma español
>   estamos debatiendo sobre el uso de la palabra "condescender" con
>   sentido negativo o peyorativo, dado que (según el DLE), la palabra
>   significa:
>
> > "Acomodarse por bondad al gusto y voluntad de alguien."
>
> En dicha definición
>   no aparece ningún sentido negativo, dado que se habla de hacer algo
>   "con bondad". Buscando en el DPD, nos encontramos con que la palabra
>   pasa a tener tres acepciones diferentes:
>
> - "acomodarse voluntariamente a los deseos de otro" (la del DLE),
> - "rebajarse a hacer algo que se considera indigno o humillante", y
> - "ser condescendiente o tolerante con algo".
>
> La primera pregunta que nos hacemos es: ¿a qué se debe esta discrepancia entre la
>   definición del DLE y las ofrecidas por el DPD? ¿No deberían estar
>   todas estas recogidas en el primero?
>
> Una segunda pregunta que nos
>   hemos hecho tiene que ver con la primera definición del DPD (que se
>   asemeja a la recogida en el DLE), en la que se alude a que el
>   acomodamiento se hace "voluntariamente", mientras que uno de los
>   ejemplos con que se ilustra dicha acepción es:
>
> > «Se ve obligado a
> >     condescender con el gusto del enfermo o a perder la casa»
>
> Nos
>   extrañó porque cuando a uno se le obliga a hacer algo, no lo hace
>   "voluntariamente" precisamente. Lo que nos lleva a preguntarnos si en
>   esa definición no sobraría la parte de "voluntariamente" (en el DPD) y
>   la de "con bondad" (en el DLE).
>
> Y por fin, la tercera duda (y la que
>   da sentido a la pregunta enlazada en nuestro sitio) que nos planteamos
>   es si la palabra está cogiendo en español el mismo sentido que tiene
>   en inglés, por el que la palabra adquiere un sentido negativo al
>   implicar que el "condescendido" se siente ofendido al ser tratado como
>   a un inferior, o si ese matiz se podía ya inferir de los significados
>   que ya tenía. ¿Se podría inferir este sentimiento a partir de las
>   acepciones indicadas por el DPD?

La respuesta de la RAE:

> En relación con su consulta, nos complace remitirle la siguiente información:
>
> En primer lugar debemos indicar que las obras académicas que menciona estudian los términos que incluyen desde diferente
>   perspectiva y están realizadas con distintos criterios. Por otra
>   parte, es importante entender que las obras lexicográficas tratan de
>   describir lo que se documenta en el uso y, por tanto, dependen de la
>   documentación que hay tenido en cuenta el lexicógrafo y de su propia
>   interpretación. El DLE no pretende ser un repertorio cerrado y
>   exhaustivo de usos correctos, sino que más bien trata de reflejar usos
>   documentados, según el criterio que se haya establecido para cada
>   edición.
>
> Por otra parte, el DPD reúne voces que presentan algún tipo de dificultad y atiende, en el caso de los verbos, de modo especial a su
>   construcción. Los artículos del DPD son pequeñas monografías y a
>   menudo incluyen acepciones o matices pertinentes para el estudio del
>   funcionamiento de un término determinado que el DLE aún no ha
>   incorporado.
>
> En cuanto a su segunda pregunta, en efecto, en esa acepción, condescender supone en principio un acto voluntario, aunque alguien
>   puede sentirse forzado por las circunstancias a condescender con
>   alguien.
>
> Finalmente, en efecto, el matiz que menciona, un tanto despectivo, se ha difundido bastante en español y, de hecho, hay ya
>   una propuesta para su incorporación al DLE.

Es interesante el hecho de que el DPD se considere como una sucesión de pequeñas monografías que ahondan en cada palabra estudiada, y que por tanto profundiza en los matices de las mismas y puede llegar a tener más contenido que el DLE. Pero más interesantes son las respuestas a las dos últimas preguntas:

- Por una parte, la RAE insiste en el hecho de que "condescender", tal y como está definida ahora, supone un acto voluntario aunque dicho acto se pueda ver forzado en ocasiones. Me sigue pareciendo algo contradictorio.
- Y por otra, lo más interesante: **hay una propuesta para incluir la acepción despectiva de "condescender" en el DLE**. Así que solo es cuestión de tiempo que el uso de "condescender" que mencionas sea recogido por la RAE que, recordemos, lo único que hace es atestiguar los usos que se le dan a las palabras. Somos los que usamos dichas palabras quienes le damos sentido a las mismas al hacerlo.

Por tanto, y para finalizar, se puede decir que sí, que el uso propuesto de "condescender" es correcto, dado que la RAE ya se ha planteado la incorporación de dicha acepción a su diccionario.

Comment: @walen me refiero a un _e-mail_, por supuesto. :-) Puedes enviar consultas a la RAE a través del [formulario en su web](http://www.rae.es/consultas-linguisticas/formulario). Con ese formulario te puedes explayar mucho más que cuando les escribes un tuit.

Comment: Yo, igual que tú, sigo sin ver que tiene de voluntario si las circunstancias te obligan. _Está semana trabajaré 12 horas al día "voluntariamente" ya que si no hago horas extras  me despiden._

Comment: @blonfu entiendo que, aunque las circunstancias te obliguen, el acto final de condescender o no (o de hacer horas extra o no) es decisión tuya. Puedes ceder a las circunstancias o rebelarte. Supongo que con "voluntariamente" se refieren a eso.

Comment: @walen en su día fui mucho de escribir cartas a mano, pero hoy día ya como que no. :-D

Comment: Si bueno, pero en ese caso nada es obligatorio.

Comment: @blonfu esto ya sería una cuestión para el sitio de [Philosophy.SE].

Comment: Solo hay que ver la propia definición de *voluntario* en el DLE y ya sacamos conclusiones, para mi está bastante claro: http://dle.rae.es/?id=c2k2usd