# ¿Se usa "carta" para referirse a un "correo electrónico"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado, sustantivos

A día de hoy, el DLE recoge el término *carta* como:

> **[carta](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7jSjnZM)**
>
> Del lat. *charta*, y este del gr. *χάρτης chártēs*.
>
> 1. f. Papel escrito, y ordinariamente cerrado, que una persona envía a otra para comunicarse con ella.

Y el término *correo electrónico* como:

> **[correo electrónico](http://dle.rae.es/?id=AyfHjz9#CyTr9dP)**
>
> 1. m. Sistema de transmisión de mensajes por computadora a través de redes informáticas.
> 2. m. Información transmitida a través de correo electrónico. *Ha recibido un correo electrónico del periódico.*

Sin embargo, la idea que yo tengo en mente sobre lo que es una *carta* no es la del papel escrito y cerrado, sino la del texto escrito en la propia carta. Es decir, pongo el foco en el mensaje y no en el medio en el que se transmite. Es por eso que a veces uso la palabra *carta* cuando en realidad quiero decir *correo electrónico*, resultando en conversaciones [como esta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/22290/es-correcto-usar-condescender-para-hablar-de-tratar-a-alguien-con-superiorida#comment35664_22373):

```
Yo:    Os muestro primero la carta que les envié, y luego su respuesta. [...]  
walen: Cuando dices "carta"... ¿te refieres a una en papel?  
Yo:    Me refiero a un e-mail, por supuesto.  
walen: Ok ok [...] al decir carta te he imaginado escribiendo con estilográfica y membrete.
```

Entiendo su confusión, por supuesto. El caso es que no sé si el uso que yo le doy a "carta" como "correo electrónico" es cosa mía: no sé si en realidad debería usar "correo" (simplemente y como forma apocopada de "correo electrónico") o si este uso de "carta" puede ser algo que se esté empezando a usar de forma (más o menos) generalizada.

Así pues: ¿Se usa "carta" para referirse a un "correo electrónico"?

Comment: Yo nunca he usado carta, a menos que tenga forma gráfica y con el estilo de una carta (en plan feliz cumpleaños o algo). Uso con preferencia *correo* —a solas— y *mensaje* (o cuando sea más preciso según contenido, *comunicado*, *noticia*, *aviso*, etc.)

Comment: Bueno, ¿y por dónde queda la carta formal y firmada que se manda como pdf attachment al correo electrónico?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yo me atrevería a decir que no. De las definiciones de la pregunta se infiere que "carta" se usa para algo físico. Yo creo que nos hemos acostumbrado a ello con el uso de anglicismos como "email" y similares y "sobrecargando" el significado otros términos como "mensaje".

Incluso mi padre, que de ven en cuando pide ayuda para redactarlos se refiere a ellos como "emails" o "notas" a lo sumo. Si me dijese que me ha mandado una *carta*, pensaría que me ha mandado una carta por correo ordinario. Igual que si me dijera que me ha mandado un [christmas](http://dle.rae.es/?id=91Imr9p) (si lo dijese mi madre que se defiende un poco más, ya habría algo de ambigüedad sobre el medio en que la ha enviado).

Además, al existir tan diversas tecnologías, la gente tiene a veces a ser precisa con la tecnología usada:

> ¿Viste lo de *email* de Luis? Yo nada más leerlo le puse un *whatsapp* a Paco. A Mario le puse también un mensaje, porque no tiene *Whatsapp*, y le dije que lo leyera cuando pudiese.

Lo que deja "carta" con el sentido tradicional de "papel (físico) que se envía a otros por correo ordinario".

Answer (score 5):

Trabajo en España, en un ámbito donde se usa mucho el correo electrónico y nunca he oído usar la palabra *carta*. Entre mis compañeros y contactos profesionales se usa mucho *correo electrónico* o, *correo* a secas, siempre que desde el contexto quede claro que no se trata de una carta escrita en papel. Así mismo, se usa bastante el término *email* o *mail*. Por lo menos en mi entorno todas estas expresiones se usan de forma intercambiable, aunque se podría decir que *correo electrónico* es la más formal de ellas.