# ¿Existe una palabra para describir la actitud de la persona que te trata como idiota?

Tags: solicitud-de-término

En Español tenemos varias palabras para describir la "actitud de la persona que.."
Ejemplos:
Condescendencia: "Actitud de la persona que se acomoda o adapta al gusto y la voluntad de otra."
Indulgencia: "Actitud o tendencia de la persona que tiene especial facilidad para perdonar las ofensas, o castigarlas con benevolencia..."
Etc.

¿Existe una palabra para describir la actitud de la persona que te trata como idiota?
Se me ocurre sobrador, pero no es exactamente la palabra que estoy buscando. El sobrador se cree superior, pero creo que no necesariamente te cree un imbécil, y te hace ver que se cree superior. En cambio la palabra que busco es alguien que te cree un completo idiota que no es capaz de darse cuenta lo que el otro está haciendo.

Comment: ¿[Condescendiente](https://dle.rae.es/condescendiente)? Relacionado: [¿Es correcto usar “condescender” para hablar de tratar a alguien con superioridad?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22290/1674).

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' si la primera palabra que me vino a la mente era condescendiente, pero cuando busque el significado para asegurarme me encontré con esa definición que resulta bastante confusa y le da otro significado

Comment: Supongo que porque es una definición algo desfasada respecto el uso que se le da últimamente, más cercano al término inglés.

Comment: Muchos conceptos en un solo término, creo que alguna vez lo pensé y lo anoté en algun lado, algo como condescendiente, paternalista, displicente.

Comment: ¿"Suficiencia"?

Comment: Con el comentario anterior quería decir "darse aires de suficiencia con alguien", pero probablemente no es exactamente lo que buscas. Por lo que se explica en la [web del Fundéu](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/condescendencia-machista-alternativa-a-mansplaining/), "condescendiente" o "paternalista" parecen las mejores opciones.

Comment: Y petulante, soberbio, engreído, creído, arrogante,  presuntuoso,  fatuo, prepotente, ... Pero la palabra que mejor define actualmente a alguien con complejo de Aristóteles es  «gilipollas», ya que quien deja patente que se cree muy listo, sin duda es un necio.

Comment: ¿Quizás **paternalista**? Va a depender del nivel de malicia de quien tenga esa actitud. Uno puede creer que alguien es pendejo y simplement no hacerle caso o condescenderle; o puede creer que alguien es pendejo y tratar a esa persona con violencia.

Comment: Todo esto es cuestión de una opinión.

Answer (score 2):

Algunas opciones por considerar:

- escarnecedor-a
- menospreciador-a
- humillador-a
- burlón

Claro que depende del contexto.

Answer (score 0):

También podría usarse vacilón, juerguista.
Efectivamente, depende mucho del contexto, podrían usarse en círculos de amistad pero quizás desentona cuando nos movemos en un círculo más profesional. En estos casos diríamos menospreciador, o simplemente burlón.

Answer (score 0):

Una persona que te trata como idiota, considero que posee una **actitud pusilánime, necia o de imbecibilidad** de razón escasa o idiotez mental.

Answer (score 0):

Otra expresión utilizada en español es **tener/mostrar aires de superioridad**.