# ¿Ha sido "horizonte eventual" una traducción aceptada para "event horizon" en algún momento?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico, adjetivos, inglés, ciencia

Recientemente hemos visto en Disney+ una película titulada *[The black hole](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0078869/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)* (en España *El abismo negro*), de 1979, considerada como la respuesta de Disney a *Star Wars*, de 1977, dado el éxito que tuvo esta.

En un momento de la película se menciona el "horizonte eventual" del agujero negro, que entiendo que será la traducción que le dio el traductor de la película al concepto de "event horizon". Hoy en día las traducciones que parecen aceptadas para este concepto son, según la web del IATE, "horizonte de observación de eventos" u "[horizonte de sucesos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizonte_de_sucesos)".

Sin embargo, y a pesar de que [conocemos los problemas de traducción de *eventual* y sus derivados](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/16380/12637), me entra la duda. Dada la definición de *[eventual](https://dle.rae.es/eventual)* en el diccionario, ¿se podría considerar "horizonte eventual" como una buena traducción de "event horizon"? Si no lo es, ¿se usó esta traducción como válida en algún momento de la historia antes de pasar a ser "horizonte de sucesos"? ¿O estamos ante un fallo del traductor como el del "Valle de la Silicona" en *[Panorama para matar](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090264/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0)*?

Comment: Quiero anotar que sí he escuchado **horizonte de eventos** pero jamás **horizonte eventual** (ver aquí https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizonte_de_sucesos).

Answer (score 5):

Para situarnos en el tiempo histórico, empiezo diciendo que el primero en usar la expresión "event horizon" es Wolfgang
Rindler, en el artículo ["Visual horizons world-models"](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1956MNRAS.116..662R), en 1956. Lo hace en el contexto de la relatividad general, aunque todavía no hace referencia a agujeros negros.

Como física, puedo decir que jamás he oído o visto usar la terminología "horizonte eventual". Personalmente, el vocabulario que siempre he usado es "horizonte de sucesos" en castellano y "horitzó d'esdeveniments" en catalán.

Buscando en casa, el texto más antiguo en que aparezca este concepto, que no esté en inglés, que he conseguido encontrar es la traducción al catalán de David Jou, de 1988, del libro *A Brief History of Time: From the Big Bang to Black Holes* de Stephen Hawking para la Editorial Crítica, que se tituló *Història del temps. Del big bang als forats negres*. Efectivamente, en él se usa "horitzó d'esdeveniments". Existe también una traducción al castellano de este mismo libro, de Miguel Ortuño, también para la Editorial Crítica, titulada *Historia del tiempo. Del big bang a los agujeros negros*, en la cual se usa "horizonte de sucesos".

Según mi experiencia, a veces existen diferencias regionales en el vocabulario técnico entre España y algunos países de América. Por ejemplo, algunos conceptos de matemáticas se expresan de manera diferente en España y en México. Por lo que he podido ver, en algunos países americanos se utiliza también la expresión "horizonte de eventos".
Por ejemplo, el [*New York Times* en español](https://www.nytimes.com/es/2019/04/11/espanol/america-latina/agujeros-negros-eht-mexico.html) llama "Telescopio del Horizonte de Eventos" al ["Event Horizon Telescope"](https://francisthemulenews.wordpress.com/2013/01/28/eht-el-radiotelescopio-que-nos-permitira-ver-sgr-a-el-agujero-negro-supermasivo-de-la-via-lactea/). Pero, en cambio, en la página web de la ESO (*European Organisation for Astronomical Research in the Southern Hemisphere*, que se suele abreviar como *European Southern Observatory*), se le denomina ["Telescopio de Horizonte de Sucesos"](https://www.eso.org/public/spain/news/eso1907).           Pero en esta monografía sobre [agujeros negros](https://www.academia.edu/37470576/Universidad_Nacional_Autonoma_De_Mexico_Agujeros_Negros_Profesora) de la Universidad Nacional Autónoma de México, aparece tanto "horizonte de sucesos" como "horizonte de eventos" al final.

Answer (score 0):

Event Horizon, en español es "Horizonte de eventos".

En Física se le llama así al rango visual al que tenemos acceso desde nuestra ubicación, es decir, hasta donde llega la luz que podemos observar en el espacio exterior, se dice "el límite de eventos".

Comment: ¡Hola! Tu respuesta es similar a otras respuestas anteriores. Si estás de acuerdo con lo que dicen y quieres mostrar tu apoyo, lo mejor es votar esas respuestas y/o dejar un comentario, para evitar tener muchas respuestas iguales. Si lo que quieres es ampliar o mejorar la información o dar otro enfoque, considera [edit]ar tu respuesta para añadir una explicación, decir de qué forma se usa en tu zona, aportar elementos históricos, etc. Más info en [answer].